# pragma directives to set frequency for dsPIC33

Tags: pic, clock, microchip, pll

currently I set the frequency of my dsPIC33EV with following code:

```
int j=100;

// setup internal clock for 80MHz/40MIPS
// 7.37/2=3.685*43=158.455/2=79.2275
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=0;        // PLLPRE (N2) 0=/2
PLLFBD=41;                  // pll multiplier (M) = +2
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0;       // PLLPOST (N1) 0=/2

__builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);     // now the PLL is configured. set the value for {COSC, NOSC} with this function to switch to FRC with PLL
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x01);     // Tell the CPU to perform the clock switch.
while(j>0)                         // This loop is here to guarantee that the clock PLL has stabilized before program operation continues
{
   if(OSCCONbits.LOCK) j--;
}
```

Now I found this can be done also without this piece of active code just by some pragma-directives configuring the related registers on start-up.

So: what pragma-commands correspond to my way of setting the clock? Is there a manual available somewhere describing them?

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the dsPIC's datasheet for something called "Configuration bits"

Comment: @m.Alin I already found them but how do they correspond to valid pragma-statements? And how do I set several bits? Shouldn't these pragma-directives be documented somewhere separately!?

Comment: They are. You can either set the config bits in the MPLAB X IDE and they get automatically converted to pragma statements (http://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:view-and-set-configuration-bits) OR you can write them manually, as explained in the X16 compiler's user manual, section 2.5.14 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002071F.pdf).

Comment: @m.Alin thanks, the configuration bits view looks great :-)